# Will C# compiler optimize this code by converting the var to const?

Tags: c#, .net

Assuming I have this function:

```
public string GenerateHash(string[] values)
{
    var secureSecret = "a secret string";  //<-- this can/should be const

    var str = new StringBuilder(secureSecret);
    foreach (var value in values) {
        str.Append(value);
    }

    return GenerateMd5Hash(str.ToString());
}
```

Clearly the `secureSecret` above can be `const`, should I bother changing this to `const` or the compiler is smart enough to know this?

Comment: semi-offtopic: i would point out that anyone looking at your dll/exe in for example ILSpy / ildasm etc can trivially read your 'secureSecret' so you might want to ask a separate question about hiding/obfuscating strings!

Comment: @tolanj, Understood.. and good point. But I just made up the code snippet above... in my case I am actually auditing huge legacy codes and getting tons of warnings saying 'variables can be made constant'... none of it actually poses security risk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the generated IL, you can see the compiler doesn't create a new string, it simply calls [`ldstr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       "a secret string"
```

The compiler is smart enough to "bake" this constant string into the generated DLL/executable you're creating.

Having said that, using a `const` conveys the writers intention, and adds to clarity to the code and enhances maintainability IMO. It will later allow you to refactor those "magic" strings more easily instead of sprinkling them everywhere in your codebase.

Comment: Got to learn this weird IL thing... looks interesting. Btw I am currently auditing huge legacy codes and there are hundreds (maybe thousands) of warning 'variable can be made constant'..., so it is probably not worth the effort fixing this.

Comment: @RosdiKasim It's not weird, it's actually quite nice :). You get to see under the covers, which is always a good thing to learn.